# How to make mouse wheel scroll to be mouse wheel hold + scroll at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing some troubles with mouse wheel scrolling when working in `unity3d` (**Game engine, further just unity**). It won't trigger to mouse wheel scroll but it triggers to mouse wheel hold + mouse wheel scroll. I didn't found any related issues for `unity` and i see only one solution to make `unity` think i'm holding mouse wheel when scrolling. Is it possible to make that mapping in `xev`, DE `cinnamon`

Comment: You mean in a code or in general you can't scroll/zoom within the Unity3D interface?

Comment: @derHugo In general while working with editor. Scroll views and 3d view don't react on mouse wheel but on mouse wheel pressed and mouse wheel spin at the same time. I didn't check in-game behaviour